# Not understanding backpropagation correctly

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, cross-entropy, softmax

So I'm trying to build a simple NN where the layers are as follows:

`linear layer`-> `ReLu` -> `Cross_Entropy_with_Softmax` -> `loss`

I'm training using the MNIST dataset (10 classes). I think I have the forward step correctly implemented. For my first training example, the correct class of $y_1 = 7$, whereas the final prediction vector from the third layer: $h_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{10 \times 1}$  has (rounded) probability values: $$h_3 = \{0.02,\ 0.01,\ 0.004,\ 0.72,\ 0.004,\ 0.004,\ 0.1,\ 0.004,\ 0.01,\ 0.04 \}$$

So clearly, the network thinks this digit is a "3" and not a "7". So in the backprop, to fix this, as per [this site](https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy), I simply subtract "1" from $h_3[y_1]$, in this case, that would $h$ become:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial h_3} = \{0.02,\ 0.01,\ 0.004,\ 0.72,\ 0.004,\ 0.004,\ 0.1,\ -0.96,\ 0.01,\ 0.04 \}$$

Now, because ReLU's derivative is a [stepwise function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042561/relu-derivative-in-backpropagation) where it is either 0 or 1 based on whether input is $h<=0$ or not, propagating Backwards it through Layer 2 (ReLu) we get:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial h_2} = \{1,\ 1, \ 1,\ 1,\ 1,\ 1,\ 1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 1 \}$$

which basically (from what I understand) only changes all the weights that the network associates with all other classes except class 7. This seems like the opposite to me?

Finally, pushing through the first layer to get the weights and biases' gradients $\partial w = \frac{\partial L}{\partial h_1}$, we get:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial h_1} = (\frac{\partial L}{\partial h_2} \cdot W) \cdot h_1 $$

for the weights.

The problem I'm getting is that after training my network for a few iterations, all predictions "stabilize" at $h_3^{t_(\infty)} = \{0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1,\ 0.1\}$ and they never change! so all the predictions become zero.

Any idea what is wrong.

I *hate* dumping code, but I've been trying for 3 days and I can't seem to get anywhere.

**[Here is my code](https://github.com/YoussefV/Neural-Network) base if you would like to check my logic**

Any help would be appreciated. Am I misunderstanding something? Is there something I can do to fix things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, $h_3$ is the input of softmax function, $h_2$ is the input of ReLU function, and $h_1$ is the input of linear layer.

Now, by chain rule, recall that
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial h_3} \frac{\partial h_3}{\partial h_2} \frac{\partial h_2}{\partial W}$$

I am fine with the derivation until $\frac{\partial L}{\partial h_3}$, but, from $\frac{\partial h_3}{\partial h_2}$, it seems problematic to me. I am not certain how you get $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1\}$; however, the derivatives should be computed from your inputs instead of outputs or derivatives. For example, if $h_3=ReLU(h_2)=[100, 0]^T$ and $h_2=[100, -100]^T$, then $\frac{\partial h_3}{\partial h_2}=[1, 0]$ because of the stepwise function.

Lastly, you compute the jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial W}$ for every $w_{ij}$, multiply all them together, and then the final gradient  $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$ is there.

Comment: Oh my god, you're completely correct! Changing `self.dw = l1.d1` to be: `dw np.matmul(np.matmul(dh2.T,dh1),l1.dw)` fixed it!